# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Question, Help Needed

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am having trouble trying to solve this question. I was given the answer to be -1 but I keep evaluating it to 0. Am I right to apply the product rule to the cosine and integral term during differentiation before applying the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Both terms after applying the product rule appear to evaluate to 0. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, that's right. Product rule, and FTC (and also chain rule because of the $x^2$). Perhaps you should show your work, and we can find a mistake

Comment: Are you applying the chain rule when differentiating the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To differentiate the integral, it's easier to split it: 
$$
\left(\int_{x^2}^x\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt\right)'
=\left(\int_{x^2}^1\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt\right)'
+\left(\int_{1}^x\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt\right)'
=-2x\sqrt{1+x^8}+\sqrt{1+x^4}.
$$
Now differentiating as a product, 
$$
F'(x)=-\tfrac\pi4\sin\tfrac{\pi x}4\,\int_{x^2}^x\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt+\cos\tfrac{\pi x}4\,\left(-2x\sqrt{1+x^8}+\sqrt{1+x^4} \right).
$$
Then, since the integral is zero at $x=1$
$$
F'(1)=0+\cos\tfrac\pi4\,(-2\sqrt2+\sqrt2)=\tfrac{\sqrt2}2(-\sqrt2)=-1.
$$

If I had to guess, I would assume that you are not using the chain rule when you differentiate the part of the integral with $x^2$.

Comment: Yes you guys are right, I missed the chain rule.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$F'(x)=-\pi/4\sin(\pi/4x)\int_{x^2}^x\sqrt{1+t^4}\operatorname dt+\cos(\pi/4x)(\sqrt{1+x^4}-2x\sqrt{1+x^8})$.

Now plug in.